# Front Panel Connector problems

Tags: motherboard, case, front-panel

I just built a new computer with an ASRock z87 in an NZXT case. The motherboard has a 9pin front panel connector, but my case only has 8 pins, the 2LEDs for HD, 2 for Power, and the switch for the powerbutton and the reset button, each with two pins. 
My LED lights won't even light up and I'm not sure if the problem is that there is one unused ground pin.

I know the power supply works as the motherboard's ethernet light and the GPU light blinks once when I turn the supply on, but otherwise nothing.

Comment: I would double-check each connection. Make sure the power switch is connected to the right pins (orientation doesn't matter) and that everything else is correct (particularly the LEDs, where orientation **does** matter).

Comment: @user55325 I checked my motherboard's manual to make sure the + and - of the LEDs especially, and I've switched the power switch and reset switch to different orientations and none have worked.

Comment: Before you worry about these case and front panel connections, you need to confirm that this new build can actually boot.  Does this PC boot if you momentarily short the two pins for the power button???

Answer (score 0):

Pin #10 (ground) in the System Panel Header is normally not used. If you have correctly connected the case connectors, the system should power ON. You can also use the Smart Switch (Power Switch) on the motherboard (you might like to disconnect the the System Panel Header first). If the system still does not power ON, the problem lies somewhere like 1x8 ATX 12V not connected to the PSU, 24 pin Power connector not properly connected, etc.